# Changing iOS app Display Name breaks @testable import

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

When I update the display name in this field
[image]

all my tests fail as `@testable import HomeApp` needs to be updates to match.

I was always under the impression `Display Name` simply appeared under your app and a few other places, I cannot work out why this is being linked to the `@testable` import in my modules.

I also the following error:

> Could not find test host for HomeTests: TEST_HOST evaluates to
>   "/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Home-hjxpvhyfkcwsqwfqzladedveshpm/Build/Products/Development-iphonesimulator/HomeApp.app/HomeApp"

Comment: I think there is a setting in Build Settings for module name, I think this is generally generated based off your display name. so just check what that is set to and change accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you update the display name field, you would also need to update Test Host field in Build Settings of your test target. The value of Test Host should be $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/(name).app/name. Let's say if your app name is HomeAppUpdated it would be $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/HomeAppUpdated.app/HomeAppUpdated. You can find Test Host field in build settings of your test target. Refer screenshot below. Hope it helps.

[image]